# How can I improve this Django query?

Tags: python, django

I have this Django query which is taking several minutes to run.

```
stat_type = 'Some String'
obj = xxx # some brand object

query = Q( Q(stat_type__icontains=stat_type) & Q(Q(brand=obj) | Q(organisation__in=obj.organisation_set.active())))

result = ViewStat.objects.filter(query).aggregate(one=Count('id', filter=Q(created__gte=timezone.now() - relativedelta(months=int(1)))), \
    three=Count('id', filter=Q(created__gte=timezone.now() - relativedelta(months=int(3)))), 
    twelve=Count('id', filter=Q(created__gte=timezone.now() - relativedelta(months=int(12)))), 
    all=Count('id', filter=Q(created__gte=timezone.now() - relativedelta(months=int(999)))))
```

**Models**

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    ...

class Organisation(models.Model):
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

class ViewStat(models.Model):
    stat_type = models.CharField(max_length=21)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    organisation = models.ForeignKey(Organisation, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
```

I have roughly 80k Organisations, 700 Brands and 10 million ViewStats.

How can I improve query performance?

Comment: It is difficult to help without more details. Have you measured the query performance somehow? Tools like `django-debug-toolbar` show the database execution plan and based on that you could tweak the query.

Comment: I assume the part `obj.organisation_set.active()` returns a list of organisations related to the brand. How many on average? One or two? Or  closer to the existing 80k?

Comment: It returns between 1 and 150.  There are `Organisation`s which are not part of a `Brand`.  I've not used `django-debug-toolbar` because this is running as a management command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to make improvements without measurements to compare against. But here are a few thoughts.

First I reordered the code a bit, so that I could understand it better.

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q
from django.utils import timezone as tz
from .models import Brand, ViewStat

stat_type = 'Some String'
some_brand = Brand.objects.first()
active_org_id_set = set(
    some_brand.organisation_set.active().values_list('id', flat=True))

time_now = tz.now()
one_month_ago = time_now - relativedelta(months=int(1))
three_months_ago = time_now - relativedelta(months=int(3))
twelve_months_ago = time_now - relativedelta(months=int(12))

result = ViewStat.objects.select_related(None)\
    .filter(stat_type__icontains=stat_type)\
    .filter(
        Q(
            Q(brand_id=some_brand.pk)
            | Q(organisation_id__in=active_org_id_set)))\
    .aggregate(
        one=Count('id', filter=Q(created__gte=one_month_ago),
        three=Count('id', filter=Q(created__gte=three_months_ago)),
        twelve=Count('id', filter=Q(created__gte=twelve_months_ago)),
        all=Count('id')))
```

Always better to use a single call to `tz.now()`.

It seems like the last filter in the aggregation (using `relativedelta(999)`) could be omitted.

I prefer to use separate variables to hold filter data, so I created `active_org_id_set`. Notice that I just collect to PKs (using `.values_list()`), not the whole `Organisation` objects, so the consumed memory is a lot less.

Then I use this `active_org_id_set` and using `organisation_id__in` instead of `organisation__in`, so that there is no need to join `Organisation` table with the `ViewStat` table.

I also filter `brand_id` instead of `brand` to avoid joining `Brand` table with the `ViewStat` table.

I make explicit use of `.select_related(None)` to reduce the joined tables to a minimum. Maybe this call is not necessary, but I don't have access to your database execution plan.